# Update or Delete in Gridbox C#

Tags: c#, .net, gridview

I have written code for Updating, Deleting, Cancelling & Editing the row in the GridBox.
Cancelling & Editing works fine. But when I Click Update or Delete, I get an error stating

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
```

For Updating, Code is

```
protected void Show_Grid_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    int id = int.Parse(Show_Grid.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
    TextBox txt_title = (TextBox)Show_Grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Title");
    TextBox txt_desc = (TextBox)Show_Grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Description");
    TextBox drop_prior = (TextBox)Show_Grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Priority");

    Update_todo(id, txt_title.Text, txt_desc.Text, drop_prior.Text);
    Show_Grid.EditIndex = -1;
    DataBind();
}
```

Database Contains,

```
id, Title, Description, Priority
```

[image: My Project GridBox]

Comment: Why are you assigning the "Show_Grid.EditIndex = -1;"?

Comment: @brokenisfixed Indexing the value from the databse according to the ID created.

Comment: Show_Grid.EditIndex = -1; should just indicate that the row is no longer being edited...

Answer (score 0):

We could do with the definition of the GridView, but here are a couple of things to check / try:

Have you specified the datakey name?

```
DataKeyNames="id"
```

Have you tried putting a breakpoint on the first line of code and stepped through to find out which line of code throws the error?

Comment: Yes I Have Checked.
`int id = int.Parse(Show_Grid.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());` throws error

Comment: What is the value of Show_Grid.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value?